# MongoDB (C#) Insert operation taking more time compared to SQL Server Insert operation(1000 times more)

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am inserting data from a file structure as shown in the image.

Folder-->sub-folder-->sub-folder-->file

Previously this data was stored in SQL Server.
The time taken to insert all this data into SQL took 26 secs, while the same data insertion into MongoDB is taking 2500 secs(not affordable).

The file is an xml file. Folder/sub-folder details are stored in one table, file details are stored in another and some tags in the file are stored in another table. 
My code recursively checks and stores data.

The insert operation simultaneously inserts into 4 collections(analogous to 4 tables during SQL insert).

I do not want to use more than one server, because I am using one server for SQL. I am also not doing any indexing explicitly except for MongoDbs _id field indexing(which is implicit)

Please find the below code-

In SQL:

```
public int AddRowToFolder(string fRelativePosition,
        string flabel, string fPhysicalName, int fParentId, int fViewOrder, EntityState fViewState,
        EntityProtection fProtection)
    {
       //Increment the Folder row count by 1.
        folderRowCount++;
        try
        {
            folderDataRow = folderDataSet.Tables[0].NewRow();

            //Adding the values to the Folder Dataset.

            folderDataRow[Convert.ToInt32(FolderColumns.RelativePosition)] = fRelativePosition;
            folderDataRow[Convert.ToInt32(FolderColumns.Label)] = flabel;
            folderDataRow[Convert.ToInt32(FolderColumns.PhysicalName)] = fPhysicalName;
            folderDataRow[Convert.ToInt32(FolderColumns.ParentId)] = fParentId;
            folderDataRow[Convert.ToInt32(FolderColumns.ViewOrder)] = fViewOrder;
            folderDataRow[Convert.ToInt32(FolderColumns.ViewState)] = fViewState;
            folderDataRow[Convert.ToInt32(FolderColumns.Protection)] = fProtection;

            folderDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(folderDataRow);                
        }

        return folderRowCount;
    }
```

In MongoDB:

```
public int AddRowToFolder(string fRelativePosition,
        string flabel, string fPhysicalName, int fParentId, int fViewOrder, EntityState fViewState,
        EntityProtection fProtection)
    {
       //Increment the Folder row count by 1.
        folderRowCount++;
        try
        {
            BsonDocument doc = new BsonDocument();

            //Adding the values to the Folder Dataset.

            doc.Add(FolderColumns.RelativePosition.ToString() , fRelativePosition);
            doc.Add((FolderColumns.Label).ToString(), flabel);
            doc.Add((FolderColumns.PhysicalName).ToString(), fPhysicalName);
            doc.Add((FolderColumns.ParentId).ToString(), fParentId);
            doc.Add((FolderColumns.ViewOrder).ToString(),fViewOrder);
            doc.Add((FolderColumns.ViewState).ToString(),fViewState);
            doc.Add((FolderColumns.Protection).ToString(), fProtection);

            foldersCollection.Insert(doc, WriteConcern.Unacknowledged);
        }

        return folderRowCount;
    }
```

The connection string I am using is :

```
DbConnString = "mongodb://localhost"
```

MongoDB write operations are expected to be faster compared to SQL, but i dont see that. Can someone help?

Comment: Please reformat your question with line breaks etc... This is quite unreadable. Also the image you are referring too is not visible.

Comment: *MongoDB write operations are expected to be faster compared to SQL* You probably have MongoDB in "don't lose data mode". Switch it to "lose data mode" (unconfirmed writes) and watch performance go up.

Comment: Without more details, how could we help? How many documents are being inserted? It's likely your schema is not optimized.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid : formatted with line breaks.But I am not allowed to insert an image, unless I have a reputation of 10.

Comment: @WiredPrairie The maximum documents in a collection will never exceed 16000. And about the schema, I am using the same schema as SQL, i.e., I just mapped SQL tables to Mongodb collections and was using same code to to dump in the data.

Comment: NoSQL databases have different design and performance characteristics. I'm not surprised that they would perform differently. Also, why do you assume MongoDb will be faster?

Comment: Expanding on what @ta.speot.js said yesterday, you should also provide the connection string you are using, to check which kind of durability you are requiring (confirmed writes, etc..).

Comment: @WiredPrairie: Please find the edits

Comment: @ Stefano Ricciardi : Please find the edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake which is very silly. I am running my application in debug mode. When I executed the exe it is faster.